# Word (.docx) document not opening in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-chrome-os, transfer

I opened a link my teacher provided to do an assignment, this link opened a Google word document (`.docx`).

When I was finished I downloaded the assignment. This was all done on my Google Chromebook. Now, it won’t let me open the downloaded assignment because it is not “supported” by Chrome.

Is there any way possible I can open this assignment?

I also have a MacBook if it could be done there I just don’t know how to transfer it.

Comment: Put it on a USB key and open it from there on your Mac.

Comment: Is it not opening in Chrome or Chromebook ?  It's a Microsoft Office file, so you need Office on your laptop.  And Chrome will not show it unless you have an addon.

Comment: I have a Chromebook which it is not opening on

Comment: So move the document as I suggested.

Comment: @RohitGupta LibreOffice should be able to open a `.docx` file.

Comment: Yes it should be able to open it.  However, DoxyLover's solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand it, you worked on a document in Google Docs and "saved it" (downloaded it to your computer. Now you cannot open the document in Chrome.

What you need to do is go to Google Docs in your browser (https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/) and click the plus sign in the lower right corner. This will open a new document. From here, click File->Open. In the popup, select "Upload" and then click "Select a file from your device".

Google Docs is designed to work primarily with documents stored on Google Drive (the cloud). It will be much easier to just keep your document on the cloud until you need to send it to someone.